# HighCharts zoom in selection event

Tags: highcharts

How to make an ajax call when the graph is zoomed in. I tried with chart.events.selection but get some javascript error.

```
selection: function(event) {
    // log the min and max of the primary, datetime x-axis
    console.log(
        Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', event.xAxis[0].min),
        Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', event.xAxis[0].max)
    );
}
```

gives error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined".
Also this function gets called when i graph is plotted infinite no of times. How to I prevent that?

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.selection 
says it should get fired when an area under graph is selected.

here is my jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/dhptnfkt/36/ (you need to un-comment the code highlighted to get the error).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example you have:

```
events: {
    selection: getSelection(event)
}
```

When you do not define the function on the spot you just need to pass the function reference, or else you are passing the parameter `event` which in your case is an undefined variable.

Instead it should look like this ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dhptnfkt/37/)):

```
events: {
    selection: getSelection
}
```